# Java getClass().getClassLoader().getResource( "/My_Form.xsd") returns null

Tags: java

Overview: last year, I supervised a contractor who ported a web application from WebSphere 5/Java 4 to Tomcat 7/Java 7.  This year, we discovered a little-used feature is broken.  Organizational changes have reduced the team working in this area to just me, so I don't have anyone to talk this over with.

I tracked the problem down to getClass().getResource("/My_Form.xsd") returning null.  I checked the obvious: the root of the war file does contain My_Form.xsd, and it sits on disk where Tomcat explodes the war file.

Here's the code (slightly refactored from the original Java 4 version):

```
package com.mycompany;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;

...

public class MyFormMaintenanceFactory {
...
    public DocumentBuilderFactory getDocumentBuilderFactory() 
    throws Exception 
    {
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();

        dbf.setValidating(true);
        dbf.setNamespaceAware(true);
        dbf.setIgnoringComments(true);
        dbf.setIgnoringElementContentWhitespace(true);
        dbf.setAttribute(JAXP_SCHEMA_LANGUAGE, W3C_XML_SCHEMA);

        String schema = "/My_Form.xsd";
        URL schemaUrl = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource( schema); 
        if (schemaUrl == null) {
            throw new Exception("Could not getResource " + schema);
        }
        dbf.setAttribute( JAXP_SCHEMA_SOURCE, schemaUrl.toExternalForm());
        return dbf;
    }
...
}
```

The output is a stack trace from the "throw new Exception(...)" line:

```
17:38:56.756(03/20) INFO  MyApp : java.lang.Exception: Could not getResource /My_Form.xsd
```

and a stack trace.

I've tried other forms of the call.  Neither of these work any better:

```
URL schemaUrl = getClass().getResource("/My_Form.xsd");
URL schemaUrl = DocumentBuilderFactory.class.getClassLoader().getResource( schema);
```

In response to another question about getResource() returning null, the suggestion was to run jar tf AppName.war.

I did that, and My_Form.xsd is at the root of the war file:

```
$ jar tf MyApp-3.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war
META-INF/
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
Global/
...
Modules/
...
shared/
theme/
WEB-INF/
WEB-INF/classes/
WEB-INF/classes/com/
...
WEB-INF/classes/resources/
WEB-INF/lib/
WEB-INF/lib/tomcat_jars/
...
WEB-INF/struts-config/
WEB-INF/taglibs/
Global/css/components/basicControl.css
...
Global/image/arrow.gif
Global/image/atsign.jpg
Global/image/banner_background.gif
...
Global/JavaScript/components/ajax.js
,,,
Global/jsp_pages/components/basicControl.jsp
Global/jsp_pages/components/basicControlTitle.jsp
...
index.jsp
...
Modules/Global_Internal/jsp_pages/body.jsp
Modules/Global_Internal/jsp_pages/layout.jsp
Modules/Global_Internal/jsp_pages/sidebar.jsp
Modules/help/FAQ.html
...
shared/searchUtil.js
...
showAllTickets.jsp
showAllTickets_body.jsp
My_Form.xsd
theme/Master.css
WEB-INF/classes/com/mycompany/MyFormMaintenanceFactory.class
WEB-INF/classes/com/mycompany/MyFormMaintenanceFactory.java
...
WEB-INF/classes/resources/MyApp.properties
...
WEB-INF/lib/commons-beanutils-1.7.0.jar
WEB-INF/lib/commons-beanutils.jar
WEB-INF/lib/commons-chain-1.2.jar
WEB-INF/lib/commons-collections-2.1.jar
...
WEB-INF/web.xml
META-INF/maven/
...
$
```

I've read the documentation and every page I can find about others having this error, and I can't figure out what the code is doing wrong.  The same call worked in WebSphere 5/Java 4.  I will gratefully accept any and all suggestions...

Comment: Try moving it to `WEB-INF/classes/resources/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resources need to be in the `/WEB-INF/classes` folder of the exploded war. The full path of the file needs to be `<root-dir>/WEB-INF/classes/My_Form.xsd`. Typically if you put the file in `src/main/resources` in the build project, modern build tools (e.g. Maven) will normally copy them correctly to the war archive at `/WEB-INF/classes` when the war archive is created.

Comment: That was it!  Thank you!